# I want a person to pass out on my adventure map but he sees too much

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making an adventure map and I want a person to pass out on the ship and not see anything at all, at that moment the chat says what just happened but when i do /effect @a minecraft:blindness 255 20 (correct amount of time) they can see blocks around them. But during the time they read the chat they are teleported to a different area. Any ideas or what I should do?

Comment: If there was nothing above the player, and 1.9 was a thing yet, I'd suggest using a levitation effect to slowly distance the player from any surrounding blocks, but alas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe tp them to a small room made of barrier blocks, and nothing around them, so it looks like they're in a void of some kind?

Answer (score 2):

You cloud try running a command to teleport them to a room made completely out of black blocks, or the floor they're on and coal blocks all around them, then teleport them back when needed.

Comment: While potentially better than the above, this still has the issue of suddenly changing the surroundings.